# Exporting figures programmatically (R2019a)

Tags: matlab, user-interface, export, ui-automation, undocumented-behavior

In MATLAB R2019a a [new way to export figures was added](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2019a&endrelease=R2019a&groupby=release&sortby=descending#mw_0ffa725b-7810-4724-9a71-2f02dac51cce) whereby the result "*is tightly cropped around the axes with minimal white space*". This feature is accessed using the axes toolbar:

[image]

My question is: **How do we invoke this new export feature programmatically?**

It should be fairly easy to get the export dialog to open for specific axes (i.e. simulate a button click), but I'm more interested in bypassing the dialog and just saving a file to disk, e.g.

```matlab
croppedExport(hAxes, outputPath);
```

P.S.
I am aware that this functionality can be achieved using a 3<sup>rd</sup> party tool like [`export_fig`](https://github.com/altmany/export_fig/).

Comment: `print -deps` also exports with a tight bounding box, unless you add `'-loose`, in which case it behaves like exporting to bitmapped formats. But be careful with the thight bounding box: if you need to compose multiple figures in your paper, it’s likely they won’t align.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## TL;DR

```matlab
matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo(hAxes, fullpath);
```

---

The tooltip of this new button says "*Export...*", which is going to help us identify it. Digging within the properties of the axes toolbar  (`struct(hAxes.Toolbar)`) we can get a glimpse of the function that is being called when the button is pressed:

```
hB = struct(struct(hAxes.Toolbar).ButtonGroup).NodeChildren(1);
%{
hB = 
  ToolbarPushButton (Export...) with properties:

            Tooltip: 'Export...'
               Icon: 'export'
    ButtonPushedFcn: @(e,d)matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportCallback(d.Axes)
%}
```

which unfortunately points to directory full of `.p` files:

```
...\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\graphics\+matlab\+graphics\+internal\+export
```

...and forces us to do proceed with trial and error. For example, we can choose a random `.p` file whose name sounds right to us, and see if we can discover its API:

```
>> matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo()
Error using matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo
Not enough input arguments. 

>> matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo('')
Error using matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo
Not enough input arguments. 

>> matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo('','')
Error using matlab.graphics.internal.export.ExporterArgumentParser/parseInputParams
'' matches multiple parameter names: 'background', 'destination', 'format', 'handle', 'margins', 'resolution', 'target'. To avoid ambiguity, specify the complete name of the parameter.
Error in matlab.graphics.internal.export.ExporterArgumentParser/processArguments
Error in matlab.graphics.internal.export.Exporter/process
Error in matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo
```

The last error message provides very interesting information, which allows us to take some educated guesses regarding the required inputs:

> ```
> 'background'  - probably background color
> 'destination' - probably where to put the file
> 'format'      - probably what is the file extension
> 'handle'      - probably the axes handle
> 'margins'     - (self explanatory)
> 'resolution'  - (self explanatory)
> 'target'      - ???
> ```

Following the "minimal" input set that is requested in the question, our next attempt is:

```matlab
membrane;
matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo('handle', gca, 'destination', 'e:\blabla.png');
```

... which creates the a file at the desired location and also returns a truecolor RGB image that is cropped just like we wanted!

[image]

Although we are done, we can try to simplify this function call even further based on the "convention" of [`saveas`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/saveas.html), which is `saveas(what, where, ...)`:

```matlab
matlab.graphics.internal.export.exportTo(gca, 'e:\blabla.png');
```

... which works (!) and so this becomes our method of choice.

Comment: Nice sleuthing!